# Target specific field in Spectral schema rule

Tags: lint, rules, spectral

I have a rule with a schema function.  The rule works fine in that it's identifying the problem, but it's also highlighting the entire object that fails the schema.  Instead, I'd like it to highlight just the specific field inside the object that's causing the problem.

I've tried adding the `field` property, but that just causes the rule to not run (without error).

```yaml
if-without-then-or-else:
  description: if requires then or else.
  severity: error
  given:
    - $
    - $..[?(@.if)]
  then:
    - function: schema
      functionOptions:
        schema:
          if:
            required:
              - if
          then:
            anyOf:
              - required: 
                - then
              - required:
                - else
```

```json
{
  "if": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up inverting the schema so that it tests the other way around.

```yaml
if-requires-then-or-else:
  description: 'The `if` keyword will be ignored unless an adjacent `then` and/or `else` keyword is present.'
  severity: error
  given:
    - $
    - $..[?(@.if)]
  then:
    - function: schema
      functionOptions:
        schema:
          if:
            not:
              anyOf:
                - required: 
                  - then
                - required:
                  - else
          then:
            properties:
              if: false
```

It's basically saying, "If either `then` or `else` are not present, then `if` is also disallowed.

This way, it targets the `if` as the thing that shouldn't be there.